# CentOS 7 : docker in docker: "Error: No space left on device"

Tags: docker, codenvy

I been tackling trying to get docker-in-docker working for a CentOS 7 image, with ubuntu as the host image.

As of now i have not started building this as a docker image. And is currently experimenting with bash on how to "get docker in docker to work"

Currently `systemctl start docker` ran inside the inner docker image CentOS gives the following error

```
Error: No space left on device
Job for docker.service failed. See 'systemctl status docker.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
```

Further investigation on the error `systemctl status docker` gives the following

```
Oct 13 04:32:08 codenvy docker[6520]: time="2015-10-13T04:32:08Z" level=info msg="Listening for HTTP on unix (/var/run/docker.sock)"
Oct 13 04:32:08 codenvy docker[6520]: time="2015-10-13T04:32:08Z" level=warning msg="Running modprobe bridge nf_nat failed with message: , error: exit status 1"
Oct 13 04:32:08 codenvy docker[6520]: time="2015-10-13T04:32:08Z" level=info msg="-job init_networkdriver() = OK (0)"
Oct 13 04:32:09 codenvy docker[6520]: time="2015-10-13T04:32:09Z" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup swap limit."
Oct 13 04:32:09 codenvy docker[6520]: time="2015-10-13T04:32:09Z" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
Oct 13 04:32:09 codenvy docker[6520]: time="2015-10-13T04:32:09Z" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
Oct 13 04:32:09 codenvy docker[6520]: time="2015-10-13T04:32:09Z" level=fatal msg="Shutting down daemon due to errors: inotify_add_watch: no space left on device"
Oct 13 04:32:09 codenvy systemd[1]: docker.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 13 04:32:09 codenvy systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Oct 13 04:32:09 codenvy systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
```

**Additional Information**

- Host OS: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
- Docker Image: [codenvy/onprem-multi](https://hub.docker.com/r/codenvy/onprem-multi/~/dockerfile/) (which is based on centos:centos7)
- Mounted Volumes

  - /sys/fs/cgroup
  - /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro
  - /mnt/docker-files-lvm/docker/codenvy/docker:/var/lib/docker
  - /mnt/docker-files-lvm/docker/codenvy/ldap:/var/lib/ldap
  - /mnt/docker-files-lvm/docker/codenvy/mongo:/var/lib/mongo
  - /mnt/docker-files-lvm/docker/codenvy/home:/home
- Privileged mode

**Note**

This is not regarding how to install codenvy, its regarding getting docker itself installed and working. Before installing codenvy

**Added: df -h**

```
Filesystem                               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/hc--dawn--vg-root             27G  3.5G   23G  14% /
none                                     4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev                                      16G   12K   16G   1% /dev
tmpfs                                    3.2G  1.1M  3.2G   1% /run
none                                     5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                                      16G   37M   16G   1% /run/shm
none                                     100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/sda1                                236M   95M  129M  43% /boot
/dev/mapper/base--storage-docker--files  886G   52G  790G   7% /mnt/docker-files-lvm
```

Note: /mnt/docker-files-lvm/docker maps to the /mnt/docker-files-lvm (which is 790GB)

Answer (score 1):

If it is a no space left problem you can configure docker to have it store images and containers elsewhere.

Since you are using systemctl the config file is located here:
`/lib/systemd/system/docker.service`

You can add a `-g` option to change where docker store things.

For example:

`ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon -g /there_is_space_here -H fd://`